# Matlab - Function taking no arguments within a class

Tags: matlab, function, class

As I do not seem to be able to edit my old question ([Matlab - Function taking no arguments but not static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576620/matlab-function-taking-no-arguments-but-not-static)), here it is again:

I am trying to implement the following:

```
classdef asset
    properties
        name
        values
    end    

    methods

        function AS = asset(name, values)
            AS.name = name;
            AS.values = values;
        end

        function out = somefunction1
            ret = somefunction2(asset.values);
            out = mean(ret);
            return
        end

        function rets = somefunction2(vals)
            n = length(vals);
            rets = zeros(1,n-1);
            for i=1:(n-1)
                rets(i) = vals(i)/vals(i+1);
            end
            return
        end
    end
end
```

But I am getting the error that somefunction1 should be static. But if it's static then it can't access the properties anymore. How would I resolve this issue?

Basically I want to be able to write something like this:

```
AS = asset('testname',[1 2 3 4 5]);
output = AS.somefunction1();
```

as opposed to writing

```
AS = asset('testname',[1 2 3 4 5]);
output = AS.somefunction1(AS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing the properties of an object in a method, you need to pass that object as argument to the method. If you don't need a specific object in order to perform a function, then make it static (belongs to the class, but does not operate on a specific object).

So, compare the original code:

```
methods

    % ...

    function out = somefunction1
        ret = somefunction2(asset.values);
        out = mean(ret);
        return
    end;

    function rets = somefunction2(vals)
        n = length(vals);
        rets = zeros(1,n-1);
        for i=1:(n-1)
            rets(i) = vals(i)/vals(i+1);
        end
        return
    end
end
```

with the correct code:

```
methods

    % ...

    % this function needs an object to get the data from,
    % so it's not static, and has the object as parameter.

    function out = somefunction1(obj)
        ret = asset.somefunction2(obj.values);
        out = mean(ret);
    end;
end;

methods(Static)
    % this function doesn't depend on a specific object,
    % so it's static.

    function rets = somefunction2(vals)
        n = length(vals);
        rets = zeros(1,n-1);
        for i=1:(n-1)
            rets(i) = vals(i)/vals(i+1);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

To call the method, you'd write indeed (please test):

```
AS = asset('testname',[1 2 3 4 5]);
output = AS.somefunction1();
```

because, in MATLAB, this is 99.99% of cases equivalent to:

```
AS = asset('testname',[1 2 3 4 5]);
output = somefunction1(AS);
```

The differences appear when you're overriding `subsref` for the class, or when the object passed to the method is not the first in the argument list (but these are cases that you should not concern with for now, until you clarify the MATLAB class semantics).

Comment: Thanks alot. It seems to work. But how does Matlab know that although I am not passing any 'obj' when calling AS.somefunction1() that the one I mean is in fact AS?

Comment: @user3805919 This is a long story but, basically, MATLAB checks the type of `AS`, sees that is an object, so checks the name `somefunction1` to see if is a property or a method. If it's a property returns the value, if it's a method then silently passes the object, i.e. `AS` as the first argument to the method. In our case is the only argument.

Comment: @user3805919 Also I would appreciate if you'd chose my posting as the answer to your question.